# How can I disable the embedded designer in XE6?

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder, delphi-xe6

In order to see multiple view in one window i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952920/how-can-i-get-delphi-2010-ide-to-show-a-split-view-with-a-form-and-its-code-at-t) answer but it seems that those options not available any more, now my question is **how configure rad studio xe6 to see more than one view** **in window** (for example actual code and designed form) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The options discussed in the question you link to still apply to XE6. The key is to disable the embedded designer which allows forms to float outside the main IDE tab set.

From XE3, the option to enable/disable the embedded designer cannot be set from the IDE options. The setting can be set by [modifying a registry key](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/09/04/disabling-the-embedded-designer-in-rad-studio-xe3/).

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\14.0\Form Design
"Embedded Designer" (REG_SZ) = "False"
```

Change the value from `True` to `False` and restart the IDE to disable the embedded designer.

This is the appropriate key for XE6. For XE5 the version is 12.0, for XE4 it is 11.0, and so on.

However, FireMonkey forms can only be designed in the embedded designer, so none of this is of any use to you unless you have a VCL project.

Comment: Options->Environment Options->Form Designer->Options-> and there is no Embedded designer (when using VCL, also try to restar xe6, but still same, Layout is on Undocked)

Comment: The option is still there, it turns out. You just cannot set it from the IDE. You need to modify a registry setting.

Comment: i change that value and restart computer but still dont see that options, do you have on your computer those options?

Comment: If you do what I say, you will be the non-embedded designer. I certainly do. No need to restart the computer though. Just the IDE.

Comment: It seems that something is different on my computer here is link of what i did (i was restart ide many times and also restart computer but still dont see anything) http://www.igreklik.com/slike/viewer.php?file=22601005799004226494.png

Comment: The screenshot shows that you have succeeded in disabling the embedded designer. Your Form4 is floating outside the main IDE tabsheet. That's the floating designer right there. Behind the Form4 designer you can see the code editor. So, this is it. We are done.

Comment: Than tanks a lot ... (now i understand that i make wrong question, what want to to do is to see split view with code and designer, but that  is another question, and as i know that is not supported in newer ide?)

Comment: No, each tab in the main IDE tabset contains either code or form. You cannot put both in one with a splitter.

Comment: IIRC, there was never an option to have form designer and editor divided by a splitter, not even in Delphi 7 or before.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis No. I guess that the asker has seen this capability in other IDEs. Perhaps.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis -> i just wonder to have more views(.cpp & .h & .dfm to see all at once like in visual studio Window->Split) see this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R1dHuekT0ao

Comment: @IanBoyd Thanks for the edit. However, you removed the `<pre>` which meant that the reg settings were formatted as Pascal and color highlighted in a bizarre fashion. That's why I used `<pre>`.

Comment: I have XE8 and others here have 10.2.
I do not have the option in XE8 (had to use the registry change).
Those that have 10.2, it appears that they added the checkbox for Embedded Editor back into the options in at least 10.2 and they think maybe 10.0

Answer (score 0):

View - desktop - classic undocked

Comment: This answer would benefit from being a bit more verbose, and/or including a screenshot or GIF showing the user action. While this may actually answer the question, the fact that it does is unclear. At a minimum, improving it would make it more likely that people will up-vote it as correct.